# Only getting relevant data from Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

Brief background: I just started recently using Pandas to read in a csv file of data. I'm able to create a dataframe from reading the csv but now I want to do some calculations using only specific columns of the dataset.

Is there a way to create a new dataframe where I only use rows where the relevant columns are not NA or 0? For example imagine an array that looks like:

```
   blah  blah1  blah2  blah3
0    1     1      1      1
1   NA    NA      1     NA
2    1     1      1      1
```

So say I want to do things with data under columns "blah1" and "blah2", but I want to only use rows 0 and 2 because 1 has an NA under the column "blah".

Is there a simple way of doing this? Thanks!

**Edit (Clarifications)**:
- I don't know ahead of time that I want to drop row 1, thus I need to be able to check for a NA value (and possibly any other placeholder value beyond just whether it is null).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [dropna](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

```
df = df.dropna(axis = 1)
```

and to select columns use this:

```
df = df[["blah1", "blah2"]]
```

Now `df` contains only cols `"blah1"` and `"blah2"` and rows `0` and `2`

### EDIT 1

To limit NaN verification to some columns you can use `isnull()`.

```
mask = df[["blah1", "blah2"]].isnull().all(axis=1)
df = df[~mask]
```

### EDIT 2

```
mask = df.B == 'placeholder'
df = df[~mask]
```

Comment: Does this just assume that I already know which row I want to drop? Is there a way to have it check as it goes whether it should drop the row or not given that it has an NA under a specific column?

Comment: What if I also want to customize by omitting a row if a value under column blah1 is something I don't want. Like if row 1 read like `0   1    1` I would still want to omit row1 because its value under the column is 0.

Basically in simple terms: I drop a row if it has a placeholder value that invalidates it from the calculation I want to do. Thus I need a way to check for a specific value beyond just if it is null

Comment: @Akimata Maybe something like `df = df[df['blah1']!='yourplaceholder']` ?

Comment: @Akimata see my EDIT 2